# Gitolite support "public repository" authority?

Tags: git, gitolite

Recent research in Git, I encounter a problem :

If I want a repository open to the public (no ssh key, only you can clone), Gitolite can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.

Yes, you can add a gitolite access rule to allow read access for everyone.

```
R @all
```

(Using the special group @all)

But, independently of gitolite, if you access a git repo with an ssh url, you would *need* an ssh key.

Without any ssh key, that means the git hosting server should support http access (and call gitolite from the httpd configuration file)